# python 3 random picking of statement from given file

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, import

hi there friend am new to python and was trying to write a program that randomly picks the questions with options from a file and displays it when a user enters the answer it should jump to next question as i mentioned i want the question to be randomly picked i have tried using "random" function but was unable to do so
below is given program.

```
    import random
a=open('1\q2.txt')
line = a.readlines()
lineq = line[1].split('$')
lineq1 = line[2].split('$')

total = random.sample (print1, print2)
print1 = print(lineq[1:5])

user_input = input()


if user_input == lineq[-1]:
    print('your answer is right')
else:
    print('your answer is wrong the answer is :',lineq[-1])

print2 = print(lineq1[1:5])

user_input = input()

if user_input == lineq1[-1]:
    print('your answer is right')
else:
    print('your answer is wrong the answer is :',lineq1[-1])


a.close()
```

**And the content in the q2.txt that is the question file is below**

> 1$Which is the largest island in the
>   world?$Srilanka$Australia$Greenland$Greenland 2$Which country is known
>   as the lady of snow?$Greenland$Canada$Pakistan$Canada 3$In which year
>   was the first electronic computer made?$1937$2000$2005$1937 4$Which of
>   these have no external ears?$Giraffe$frog$cat$frog 5$Which of the
>   following is a carnivore?$Vulture$crow$goat$Vulture

Kindly please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that each question is in a new line in that text file.
Here you go:

```
from random import shuffle

f = open('q2.txt')

lines = f.readlines()

shuffle(lines)

for line in lines:
    qnum, question, *choices, answer= line.split('$')
    user_input = input("{} ({}) ".format(question, ", ".join(choices)))
    answer = answer.rstrip()
    if user_input == answer:
        print('your answer is right')
    else:
        print('your answer is wrong the answer is', answer)

f.close()
```

The line `answer = answer.rstrip()` just strips the trailing newline character.

Comment: Thank you buddy it helped me a lot there are many new things i need to learn from the program you gave thank you any way..